# Try-catch issue powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function Test($cmd)
{
          Try
         {
                  Invoke-Expression $cmd -ErrorAction Stop
         }
         Catch
         {
                  Write-Host "Inside catch"
         }

         Write-Host "Outside catch"
}

$cmd = "vgc-monitors.exe"  #Invalid EXE
Test $cmd

$cmd = "Get-Content `"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PS\lib\11.txt`""
Test $cmd
```

#

Call Test() first time with $cmd = "vgc-monitors.exe" (this exe does not exist in system)

*Exception caught successfully

*Text "Inside catch" "outside catch" printed

### #

Call Test() second time with `$cmd = "Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PS\lib\11.txt""` (11.txt does not exist in the specified path)

*Exception NOT caught

*Text "Inside catch" not printed"

*Get the following error message

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PS\lib\11.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Content <<<<  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PS\lib\11.txt"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Admini...p\PS\lib\11.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Question:

I want the second exception to be caught. I cannot figure out the error in my code.

Thanks

Jugari

Answer (score 2):

You're applying `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Invoke-Expression`, which executes just fine. To make the error action directive apply to the invoked expression you'd need to append it to `$cmd`:

```
Invoke-Expression "$cmd -ErrorAction Stop"
```

or set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`:

```
$eap = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
  Invoke-Expression $cmd
} catch {
  Write-Host "Inside catch"
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $eap
```

The latter is the more robust approach, as it doesn't make assumptions about `$cmd`.

Comment: What if `$cmd` happens to be an exe?  Or for some reason they decided to end the command with a `;`?

Comment: @KeithHill Then he'd just have to stick with second option I suggested.

Comment: That would be preferable I think.  :-)